# Unlist a subdomain or directory according to robotstxt.org

Tags: robots.txt

According to robotstxt.org

> The first answer is a workaround: You could put all the files you
>   don't want robots to visit in a separate sub directory, make that
>   directory un-listable on the web (by configuring your server)

How do I configure my server to have an unlisted directory or subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server and its configuration.

As it may be a privacy/security issue to list the content of a folder, most servers will probably not do it by default. Some servers might display folder content only if there is no `index.html` file.

For Apache, see [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

You can easily test it if your server lists content or not:

1. create a folder `test`
2. add a `dummy.txt` file
3. visit the URL of this folder, e.g. `http://example.com/test/`

If you get an error message, your server doesn’t list content. If you see a link list containing `dummy.txt`, your server does list content.